# Micronaut execute NettyHttpRequest with DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, http, proxy, client, micronaut

I'm implementing a pattern-based request redirection to another microservice using an HttpFilter. My filter implementation simply executes the request with a custom http client.

```
@Override
public Publisher<? extends HttpResponse<?>> doFilter(HttpRequest<?> request, FilterChain chain) {
  return httpClient.exchange(request);
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that `httpClient` is a [DefaultHttpClient](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/client/netty/DefaultHttpClient.html) and request is a [NettyHttpRequest](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/server/netty/NettyHttpRequest.html) and it looks like they are not compatible.

```
// httpClient.exchange(request) -> ClassCastException on the request
java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.micronaut.http.server.netty.NettyHttpRequest cannot be cast to class io.micronaut.http.MutableHttpRequest

// httpClient.exchange(request.mutate()) -> ClassCastException on the response
java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.micronaut.http.client.netty.FullNettyClientHttpResponse cannot be cast to class io.micronaut.http.MutableHttpResponse
```

Is it wrong this approach for forwarding some specific requests to other microservice?
Is it wrong to use a DefaultHttpClient in this case? How can I make it work?

Comment: Is this a bug? Note a similar issue was reported for ProxyHttpClient not long ago: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/6073